# CodeBlocks not running code

Tags: codeblocks

I was trying to run a code in code Blocks but every time i try to build&run it the following message is displayed in the bottom of Program

```
-------------- Build: Debug in will it work (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c "/home/TwTOoth/Documents/will it work/main.cpp" -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o "bin/Debug/will it work" obj/Debug/main.o   
Output file is bin/Debug/will it work with size 28.28 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

what seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

According to your Build Log message, your build seems fine here.

If it was not the case, you would have a message like this at the end of the text:

> Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
>
> 2 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)

So if your build is fine, maybe this is your "run" which is not fine (or the content done for the output inside your implementation). Have you tried to do a "Build" then a "run" instead of "build & run"?